# Need to host shiny app on the internal server(having no internet connectivity)

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I am new to R.

I build a shiny app on my local system and now want to host it on an internal server.I have installed shiny server on the server and copied my app into srv/shiny-server/app.R.

Now I am not sure about the next step.Please assist.

> How to link it with any address and as on the server no packages are available.How to proceed further.

Comment: Have you checked tester samples on server? You know, "it' alive!" page on ip-address:3838?
your app should be based on its own folder like /srv/shiny-server/app/app.R, so then you can access it by ip-address:3838/app.
If you'll have unnecessary files in main folder (like /srv/shiny-server/app.R), it most probably would confuse shiny server.
check out the manual for shiny server for more info: http://docs.rstudio.com/shiny-server/

Comment: Thanks a lot.Now its very clear to me.I have not checked any sample yet as on the server there are no required packages installed (for shiny app) and there is no internet connectivity as well.I need to manually download binaries for each package on my local system and will need to transfer it on the server and will install..(it is a long procedure)Thanks again!!If you have any idea that how to install packages without internet connectivity please assist.

Comment: There are plenty of example out there how to set this up

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-shiny-server-on-ubuntu-16-04